# Angular 2 ComponentRef unimplemented

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I'm looking for a way to get the ComponentRef of a component in my angular1 and 2 hybrid app. Because I have to use the UpgradeAdapter bootstrap rather than the angular2 I don't get a promise with the ComponentRef to the root back from bootstrap function. I tried injecting it in to my component:

```
constructor(@Inject(ComponentRef) ref){
}
```

This ref doesn't seem to be correct however. All of the methods and properties on it throw an exception: `uncaught unimplemented` error.

I'm using RC1.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am in the same boat here ..

Comment: Find anything ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never found anything. It seems to have resolved in a later release.